# Convert hierarchical dictionary to HTML nested dropdown

Tags: python, html, recursion, drop-down-menu, nested

I have a list of dicts like this,
but we may have more depth and so more id and pids ...

```py
WIDGETS = [
    {"id": 1, "pid": 0, "url": "/upload"},
    {"id": 2, "pid": 0, "url": "/entry"},
    {"id": 3, "pid": 0, "url": "/report"},
    {"id": 4, "pid": 3, "url": "/reppremium"},
    {"id": 5, "pid": 4, "url": "/reppremiumsum"},
    {"id": 6, "pid": 4, "url": "/reppremiumfull"},
    {"id": 7, "pid": 3, "url": "/repcommission"},
    {"id": 8, "pid": 7, "url": "/repcommissionsum"},
    {"id": 9, "pid": 7, "url": "/repcommissionfull"},
    {"id": 10, "pid": 3, "url": "/repportions"},
    {"id": 11, "pid": 10, "url": "/repportionssum"},
    {"id": 12, "pid": 10, "url": "/repportionsfull"},
    {"id": 13, "pid": 0, "url": "/adduser"},
    {"id": 14, "pid": 0, "url": "/exportdb"},
    {"id": 15, "pid": 0, "url": "/importdb"},
]
```

and i want to convert it to a HTML nested / multilevel dropdown like this:

```
main menu -> /upload
             /report -> /reppremium    ->  /reppremiumsum
                                       ->   /reppremiumfull

                     -> /repcommission ->  /repcommissionsum
                                       ->  /repcommissionfull


                     -> /repportions   ->  /repportionssum
                                       ->  /repportionsfull
             /adduser
             /exportdb
             /importdb
```

i have tried some codes , but it doesnt work properly , as i know it needs a recursive function...

```py
def get_widgets(widgets,text='',pid=0,text_m=''):
    childs = get_childs(pid,widgets)
    for child in childs:
 
        pidn = child['id']
        n = get_childs(pidn,widgets)
        print(n,'for id',pidn)


        if len(n) != 0:
            text += f'''
            <li class="nav-item dropend">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{ child['url'] }" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                { child['url'] }
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start">
            '''
            pid_new = child['id']
            get_widgets(widgets,text,pid_new)
            text += '</ul></li>'
            print(text)
            text_m += text
        else:
            #print(n,'n')
            text += f'''
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="{ child['url'] }">{ child['url'] }</a>
            </li>
            ''' 
            text_m += text
    


        text = ''



 
    return tex
```

i expect the code to show an html multilevel dropdown ... but populated by WIDGETS...

Comment: Can you show the HTML output you expect for that input?

Comment: @s.b yes dear , ill try it out now, but it seems perfect, thanks , ill mark it after completing the part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed this should be done recursively and there are several approaches to solve it.

Here is the complete code:

```py
WIDGETS = [
    {"id": 1, "pid": 0, "url": "/upload"},
    {"id": 2, "pid": 0, "url": "/entry"},
    {"id": 3, "pid": 0, "url": "/report"},
    {"id": 4, "pid": 3, "url": "/reppremium"},
    {"id": 5, "pid": 4, "url": "/reppremiumsum"},
    {"id": 6, "pid": 4, "url": "/reppremiumfull"},
    {"id": 7, "pid": 3, "url": "/repcommission"},
    {"id": 8, "pid": 7, "url": "/repcommissionsum"},
    {"id": 9, "pid": 7, "url": "/repcommissionfull"},
    {"id": 10, "pid": 3, "url": "/repportions"},
    {"id": 11, "pid": 10, "url": "/repportionssum"},
    {"id": 12, "pid": 10, "url": "/repportionsfull"},
    {"id": 13, "pid": 0, "url": "/adduser"},
    {"id": 14, "pid": 0, "url": "/exportdb"},
    {"id": 15, "pid": 0, "url": "/importdb"},
]


def build_HTML(d, text=""):
    for (id_, url), children_list in d.items():
        text += f"<li>{url}"

        if children_list:
            text += "<ul>"
            for dd in children_list:
                text += build_HTML(dd, "")
            text += "</ul>"

        text += "</li>"

    return text


def set_recursive(obj, d):
    for (id_, url), children_list in d.items():
        if obj["pid"] == id_:
            children_list.append({(obj["id"], obj["url"]): []})
            return
        else:
            for item in children_list:
                set_recursive(obj, item)



root = {(0, "/main-menu"): []}
while WIDGETS:
    d = WIDGETS[0]
    set_recursive(d, root)
    del WIDGETS[0]

print(f"<ul>{build_HTML(root)}</ul>")
```

output:

```
<ul><li>/main-menu<ul><li>/upload</li><li>/entry</li><li>/report<ul><li>/reppremium<ul><li>/reppremiumsum</li><li>/reppremiumfull</li></ul></li><li>/repcommission<ul><li>/repcommissionsum</li><li>/repcommissionfull</li></ul></li><li>/repportions<ul><li>/repportionssum</li><li>/repportionsfull</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>/adduser</li><li>/exportdb</li><li>/importdb</li></ul></li></ul>
```

#### Explanation:

In `set_recursive()` function, we basically create another data structure in form of:

```
{(0, '/main-menu'): [{(1, '/upload'): []},
                     {(2, '/entry'): []},
                     {(3, '/report'): [{(4, '/reppremium'): [{(5, '/reppremiumsum'): []},
                                                             {(6, '/reppremiumfull'): []}]},
                                       {(7, '/repcommission'): [{(8, '/repcommissionsum'): []},
                                                                {(9, '/repcommissionfull'): []}]},
                                       {(10, '/repportions'): [{(11, '/repportionssum'): []},
                                                               {(12, '/repportionsfull'): []}]}]},
                     {(13, '/adduser'): []},
                     {(14, '/exportdb'): []},
                     {(15, '/importdb'): []}]}
```

This is now a dictionary of elements which keeps track of every sub-elements. The way it works is that for every element, it recursively checks the data structure to see if it can find its *"parent"*. If it finds, it belongs to that list. After we handle that we just delete it from the records.

In `build_HTML()` function you create your string in its most compressed form(browser's parser doesn't care).

The main point in this function is that you need to open `<ul>` before entering to the `children_list` and close it after that.

**Note:** This solution works properly because your data is sorted in the way that for appending every child, it's parent is already appended.

If you render that string:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>


<body>

    <ul><li>/main-menu<ul><li>/upload</li><li>/entry</li><li>/report<ul><li>/reppremium<ul><li>/reppremiumsum</li><li>/reppremiumfull</li></ul></li><li>/repcommission<ul><li>/repcommissionsum</li><li>/repcommissionfull</li></ul></li><li>/repportions<ul><li>/repportionssum</li><li>/repportionsfull</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>/adduser</li><li>/exportdb</li><li>/importdb</li></ul></li></ul>

</body>
```

The beautified version of that string is:

```html
<ul>
    <li>/main-menu
        <ul>
            <li>/upload</li>
            <li>/entry</li>
            <li>/report<ul>
                    <li>/reppremium
                        <ul>
                            <li>/reppremiumsum</li>
                            <li>/reppremiumfull</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>/repcommission
                        <ul>
                            <li>/repcommissionsum</li>
                            <li>/repcommissionfull</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>/repportions
                        <ul>
                            <li>/repportionssum</li>
                            <li>/repportionsfull</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>/adduser</li>
            <li>/exportdb</li>
            <li>/importdb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```